# Assertion Error : App Version has already been registered

Tags: javascript, ember.js, build, frontend, ember-cli

Im using ember to develop a project.
Please help me with this error. Im unable to run my project on local. After hitting 
`ember server` the build is successful. But on hitting the `http://localhost:4200`
Loads empty page with console error.

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The initializer 'App Version' has already been registered
    at assert (index.js:172)
    at Function.initializer (index.js:420)
    at registerInitializers (index.js:27)
    at loadInitializers (index.js:68)
    at Module.callback (app.js:25)
    at Module.exports (loader.js:106)
    at requireModule (loader.js:27)
    at app-boot.js:3
```

Unable to understand what to do. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did a [code search](https://emberobserver.com/code-search?codeQuery=App%20Version) to see where that initializer might exist and it looks to be part of `ember-cli-app-version`.

In your place I would remove `ember-cli-app-version` from your app with `npm uninstall --save-dev ember-cli-app-version` and then run `ember serve` again. The purpose of this addon is to make it easy to see your app's version number in the ember inspector, but that's not a big deal so removing it won't break anything and should get you moving forward.

If you want to investigate the issue further try searching your code base (including node_modules) for `App Version` to see where a duplicate exists.

Comment: Yes, I tried navigating through the code. There were two `App Version` being called in the list of initializers. So I recursively removed all the files and folders inside node_modules. then did an `npm install`. Solved the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was due to the iCloud sync being active in my Macbook.
Turning iCloud sync off should solve the problem.